# Rails - How to link to form of another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to `link_to` a "create device form" from the `show_rfid` partial of the `show_cabinet` of my app.  I would like to pass the `rfid_id` and `cabinet_id` to be used in the new device that will be created.  What is the syntax of the link_to statement?  This is what I have so far:

```
<%= link_to "Create New Device (non-functional)", ???????, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Bonus:  I would like the submit button on the create device page to take them back to the `show_cabinet` page if that is where they're coming from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<%= link_to "Create New Device (non-functional)", new_device_path({:rfid => @rfid_id, cabinet_id: => @cabinet_id}), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

assuming `Device` is the class and that your `new` action can accept those parameters optionally.

Comment: Thank you.  That takes me to the form page of the Device object.  Now, how do I use the elements I've passed in to pre-populate the fields?